# Google analitycs looses referer when redirecting from within an Iframe

Tags: redirect, iframe, google-analytics

I have a landing page on my domain "**mysite.com/landing**"

On that landing page I have an Iframe with register widget. 
Iframe sourse comes from "**mysite.com/iframe**"

When user registers in Iframe widget, I send a form from parent window, using target="_parent".

The problem is - I loose all my referrer's information - after I send the register form and redirect user, document.referer is "mysite/iframe".

Is there a way to tell google analytics keep the original document.referrer with wich user originally came to "mysite.com/landing"? I use universal analytics if it make the difference.

tracking code:

```
 (function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
 new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
 j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
 '//www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
 })(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-M...');
```

Comment: could you post the tracking code and how it looks like in both page/iframe?

Comment: so I see that you are using GTM - what tags/rules do you have setup?

Comment: i've understood that i'm trying to catch button click event - but the button is in Iframe so gtm script doesnt see it. Trying to find out how to catch events, happened in iframes on the page. Any ideas?

Comment: maybe this will be of help: https://plus.google.com/+SimoAhava/posts/gp7kx7azMMS